# What are permission names for the below capabilities in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What are permission names for the below capabilities in a SQL Server database:

- You can READ the records
- You can Update/Insert/Delete / Read
- You Create / Alter / Delete Views, Tables, Stored procs
- You can do all the things above

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SELECT
- UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE
- ALTER xx
- It depends: CONTROL DATABASE or CONTROL SCHEMA

See MSDN for more

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx